# recordMyDesktop stopped working after upgrade

Tags: 10.10, recordmydesktop

I've done the upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10 from Ubuntu 10.04, and recordMydesktop don't work now. If I start it from command line it seam to work, but the interface don't start and I have this error:

```
    Initial recording window is set to:
X:0   Y:0    Width:1680    Height:945
Adjusted recording window is set to:
X:0   Y:0    Width:1680    Height:944
Your window manager appears to be Metacity

Initializing...
Buffer size adjusted to 4096 from 4096 frames.
Opened PCM device default
Recording on device default is set to:
1 channels at 22050Hz
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
Bad Access on XGrabKey.
Shortcut already assigned.
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
Bad Access on XGrabKey.
Shortcut already assigned.
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
Bad Access on XGrabKey.
Shortcut already assigned.
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
Bad Access on XGrabKey.
Shortcut already assigned.
Capturing!
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
Bad Access on XGrabKey.
Shortcut already assigned.
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
Bad Access on XGrabKey.
Shortcut already assigned.
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
Bad Access on XGrabKey.
Shortcut already assigned.
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
Bad Access on XGrabKey.
Shortcut already assigned.
```

Comment: I use lubuntu 17.10 and have exactly that problem. ..

Answer (score 3):

Thanks fot the answers, proprably my problem it's for a dirty upgrad from Ubuntu 9.10 to 10.04 and now the upgrade to the 10.10. IMHO, the problem is in the applet bar up-right, time ago after an update I've lost the Shutdown menù.

I will formatt and install a clear 10.10 version from ISO.

Recrod myDesktop save in ogv with Theora codec and it's a best quality that I never seen, converting it in a sequence of image, there isn't blur and you can use they for a textual tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to package changes in Ubuntu 10.10 which has affected recordMyDesktop. It's likely a update to recordMyDesktop itself will be required to fix the error you are seeing

Not to offend the developers of recordMyDesktop, but it's a very basic program. If your looking for a more powerful recording tool check out ffmpeg, it's able to screen capture both audio and video perfectly. It's a command line based recorder, but the guide below explains everything you need to know about it, along with detailed installation instructed.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095

Comment: I have an easy to use script that I created after recordMyDesktop failed to work properly for me. The script uses ffmpeg and parec. http://okiebuntu.homelinux.com/blog/?p=175

Answer (score -1):

There are lot alternatives to recordMyDesktop .I am using 'XVidCap' to record my desktop. nice app output can be saved in MPEG and AVI formats. It is available in the software center

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/t6vUO0A.png
Can't find it in the default repos with software center under 14.04. Any backport PPA? Do you have any info?